# Many-to-Many Query in Entity Framework 6 without Junction Tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have several entites involved in one-to-many and many-to-many relationships. Entity framework doesn't expose models for the generated junction tables, so I'm trying to figure out how to use navigation properties to produce the equivalent result to this query:

```
select p.Name, p.Description, p.Version, p.Filename, f.Name as Platform, p.ReleaseNotesURL
from packages p
inner join Platforms f on (f.ID = p.PlatformID)
inner join PackageGroups pg on (pg.Package_ID = p.ID)
inner join Groups g on (g.ID = pg.Group_ID)
inner join GroupCustomers gc on (gc.Group_ID = g.id)
where gc.Customer_ID = @customerId AND p.IsPublished = 1
```

[image]

**SOLVED**: Thanks to [octavioccl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394631/octavioccl) I got the solution I was after:

```
var request = HttpContext.Request;
var appUrl = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;
var baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority, appUrl);

var items = from s in db.Packages
            join p in db.Platforms on s.PlatformID equals p.ID
            from g in s.Groups
            from c in g.Customers
            where c.ID == customer.ID && s.IsPublished
            select new
            {
                Name = s.Name,
                Description = s.Description,
                Version = s.Version,
                PackageURL = baseUrl + "/PackageFiles/" + s.Filename,
                Platform = p.Name,
                ReleaseNotesURL = s.ReleaseNotesURL
            };

return Json(items.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: According to your diagram, there is no relationship between Packages and Platforms - is your foreign key missing?

Comment: If you are using database-first i.e. an .edmx file, EF does not generate tables for you.   You need to define a FK on your packages table and EF will generate a navigation property.

Comment: why/how do you get a `PackageGroups` entity ?

Comment: Also - as far as I know - you cannot use navigation properties alone to generate a many-to-many query.  You need the intermediate table as you have shown.  Anyone who has experience to the contrary please comment.

Comment: I am using code-first. I updated the FK on the Package entity to refer to Platforms. @JoeEnos

Comment: @tschmit007 because there is a many-to-many between packages and groups...and it's a table, not an explicit entity

Comment: As it appears in your query: it is an entity.

Comment: Do you use code first on existing database or on non existing database (default) ?

Comment: @tschmit007 it's not an Entity Framework entity. It's just a table EF generated for the association.

Comment: Ok sorry, due to highlight ii thinked it was a linq query. So you use standard code first and the path to your answer is a merge of the two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the names of your entities and navigation properties but I think you could do something like this:

```
int id=10;
var items = from s in db.Packages
            join p in db.Platforms on s.PlatformID equals p.ID
            from g in s.Groups
            from c in g.Customers
            where c.Id==id && s.Published==1
            select new {Name=s.Name, 
                        Description=s.Description,
                        Version= s.Version,
                        FileName= s.Filename,
                        PlatformName=p.Name,
                        ReleaseNoteUrl=p.ReleaseNoteUrl};
```

Answer (score 0):

In OnModelCreating try something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PackageGroup>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Groups)
            .WithRequired(x => x.PackageGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Group_ID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<PackageGroup>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Packages)
            .WithRequired(x => x.PackageGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Package_ID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Edit:  Having defined the relationships described above, you can then use a query like this (psudocode):

```
var query = 
    from g in db.groups
    from pg in g.packageGroups
    from p in pg.packages
    where g.Name = "Something" && p.Version = 1
    select new { yada yada }
```